# Is there a way to generate a PDF and PRINT article using the {loadposition} in Joomla?

Tags: pdf, printing, joomla, module

I would like to create PDF and print article that includes module (I'm using loadposition). Is there a way to do that? How should I create PDF and use print option in module?

---

**SOLVED**

I have implemented in my module jspdf (more about it:http://code.google.com/p/jspdf/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear on your question...

- are you wanting the Print/PDF functions of Joomla! 1.5 to include module content in an article that has been inserted using `{loadposition modulename}`?

If so, then you're out of luck, the Print/PDF functions are only handed the article content and the defined `print.css` to generate the view. The other problem with the PDF button was that it didn't use any content plugins that may be used in an article so you would see the `{loadmodule modulename}` tag rather than the modules content in the PDF.
The only relatively easy work around would be to have a custom button to tell the browser to perform a print page calling the entire view with a print template.

- Or do you want to include a module with a PDF + Print button?

Any module that could provide a Print/PDF button would have to do a lot of work to determine which article is was actually printing - I'm not aware of any that do that as Joomla! has built-in buttons for these services in each article view.

In Joomla! 1.5 there is a built-in set of buttons for the Articles (ie. com_content), they include Print, PDF and an Email service. In the Joomla! 2.5 line (ie. 1.6+) [PDF generation has been removed](http://docs.joomla.org/What%27s_new_in_Joomla_1.6#Removed_features).

However, you can add PDF facilities back to Joomla 2.5 by using one of the "[Print & PDF](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/print-a-pdf)" extensions on the [Joomla Extension Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/). The most comprehensive one we've used for clients is [Phoca PDF](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/print-a-pdf/7492), personally we don't provide print to PDF functions on our websites.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want the PRINT/PDF functions to include in my module. When I use them, I got PDF with text {loadposition module} but I think that I find a solution.